# Python: using property getter as a callable function?

Tags: python

Getters for Python's properties are not callable, for example as a 'key' in list.sort. Is it right to simply use **get** to use the property as a callable getter method?

```python
import random


class Numbers:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self._num = num

    # getter property is not callable (e.g., in list.sort())
    @property
    def num(self):
        return self._num

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._num)


nums = []

print("\nSorted numbers")
nums.sort(key=Numbers.num.__get__)  # Error raised without __get__
for n in nums:
    print(n, end=' ')
```

I appreciate if someone would confirm this is the right way or suggest a better way of doing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lambda`, then it doesn't matter whether it's an ordinary attribute or a getter.

```
nums.sort(key = lambda n: n.num)
```

Comment: Or `operator.attrgetter('num')`, which is about 2x faster than the user-defined function.

Comment: Premature optimization

Comment: I don't see it as an optimization so much as something that more clearly expresses what you want. (Remember,  lambda expressions were slated for removal from Python 3, and `attrgetter` and the like were added to fill the use-cases that lambda expression left vacant. The lambda expression eventually survived, but its intended replacements were kept as well.)

Comment: I think this expresses it pretty clearly. Simple lambda expressions are easy to understand.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks! This is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the property's getter via its `fget` attribute.

```
nums.sort(key=Numbers.num.fget)
```

It might be simpler, though, to simply provide a `__lt__` method that compares `Numbers` instances by their `_num` attributes:

```
# Ignoring issues of other not being an instance of Numbers itself...
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self._num < other._num
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about fget attribute.